# SQL - Window function to get values from previous row where value is not null

Tags: sql, window, lag, exasolution

I am using Exasol, in other DBMS it was possible to use analytical functions such `LAST_VALUE()` and specify some condition for the `ORDER BY` clause withing the `OVER()` function, like:

```
select ...
LAST_VALUE(customer) 
OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date_x DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ) as the_last
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> ERROR:    [0A000] Feature not supported: windowing clause (Session:
>   1606983630649130920)

the same do not happen if instead of `AND 1 PRECEDING` I use: `CURRENT ROW`.

Basically what I wanted is to get the **last value** according the Order by that is NOT the current row. In this example it would be the $customer of the previous row.

I know that I could use the `LAG(customer,1) OVER ( ...)` but the problem is that I want the previous customer that is NOT null, so the offset is not always 1...

How can I do that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select lag(customer) over (partition by id
                           order by (case when customer is not null then 1 else 0 end),
                                    date
                          )
```

You can do this with two steps:

```
select t.*, 
       max(customer) over (partition by id, max_date) as max_customer
from (select t.*,
             max(case when customer is not null then date end) over (partition by id order by date) as max_date
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: No, it does not. I will update tomorrow my question with an example of the raw data. Thanks anyway.